# rename multiple files with rename command?

Tags: linux, shell, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I rename a lot of files using a regex?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24107/how-can-i-rename-a-lot-of-files-using-a-regex)
>   [Rename All Files with a Certain Name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24761/rename-all-files-with-a-certain-name)

There are files with

```
ORDER_EVENTS_SOMETHING_20120117.log
ORDER_EVENTS_SOME2_20120117.log
ORDER_EVENTS_CHARS_20120117.log
```

and so on..

I need to rename them to

```
ORDER_EVENTS_SOMETHING_20120113.log
ORDER_EVENTS_SOME2_20120113.log
```

and so on..

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rename 's/20120117/20120113/' ORDER_EVENTS_*20120117.log
```

This assumes that all the files to be renamed are in the same directory.

Answer (score 6):

do:

```
rename -n 's/(.*)_20120117/$1_20120113/' ORDER_EVENTS*
```

once you sure this is it, remove the `-n` option.

Comment: Nikhil did easier regexp (+1). Anyhow I will leave this for the reference.

Comment: +1 for hint on `-n` switch

Answer (score 0):

Or use [mmv](http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html):

```
  mmv "*17.log" "#1\13.log"
```