# command to mass rename files according to pattern

Tags: bash, rename

I have a lot of files in a directory that are named as follows ID_OTHER_STUFF.txt  I'd like to rename them all to ID.txt.  This isn't a duplicate because I don't know how to specify this pattern.

Comment: You can't rename them all to the same name in the same directory - you would have to move them all to different directories.

Comment: moving them all to a different directory is fine, thanks

Comment: This also appears to be a duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24761/rename-all-files-with-a-certain-name

Comment: Can you please give sample input/output for your command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch renaming files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files)

Comment: it's "unclear what i'm asking" after i've accepted an answer that addresses exactly what i'm asking?  great policework....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the `perl` script `prename`, which is symlinked to `rename` on Debian based distros.

```
rename -n 's/^([^_]*)_.*/$1.txt/' *_*.txt
```

Remove the `-n` once you are sure it does what you want.

Comment: BTW obviously the ID part is a stand-in for the number.  Rather than putting them in different directories according to ID, could we put them all in one directory, but the files just named ID? This answer is very good thank you.

Comment: @Walrus, should do the job now, after a quick perl vs regex learning session for me.

Comment: Becareful w/ the `rename` command  there's the Perl script version (Debian/Ubuntu) and an actual executable (Red Hat distros). http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24761/rename-all-files-with-a-certain-name.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use your shell's parameter expansion to manipulate the name, like this:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  mv $file ${file/_*/}.txt
done
```

E.g.:

```
$ ls -1
1_foo_bar.txt
2_foo_bar.txt
$ for file in *.txt
for> do
for> mv $file ${file/_*/}.txt
for> done
$ ls -1
1.txt
2.txt
```

Look up **Parameter Expansion** in your shell's man page for more details about `${name/pattern/repl}` usage.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your files are:

1_other_stuff.txt
2_other_stuff.txt
3_other_stuff.txt

You could do:

```
$ seq 1 3 | xargs -I ID mv ID_other_stuff.txt ID.txt
```

Comment: Wont work, `mv` only takes more that 2 arguments when the last one is a directory. Then it puts the files in that directory. Using `mv` requires one run per file. You can do this in a loop or use `rename` which is the standard tool for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: I am giving two args to mv here.

Comment: Apologies, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `mv` them in a loop, mini bash script, there are several variations. in this Question [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files).

Comment: I'm looking for a line of code that turns that particular pattern into the other specified pattern, thanks.

Comment: all of the answers in that post can be written on one line, and contain the fundamental principles behind both of the other two answers, given to your question here.