# rename files based on the directory name

Tags: linux, directory, filenames, rename

```
for i in L*;
do
cd $i
find . -type f -name 'botrytis_cinerea_T12345.*' -exec rename 's/botrytis_cinerea_T12345/"$i"/g' {} \;
done
```

I get the error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec' rename: not enough arguments

Usage:  rename [options] expression replacement file...

Options:  -v, --verbose    explain what is being done  -s, --symlink   act on symlink target

 -h, --help     display this help and exit  -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see rename(1).
```

Comment: You're using the "other" `rename`. Possible duplicate of [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275254/why-is-the-rename-utility-on-debian-ubuntu-different-than-the-one-on-other-distr)

Comment: Actually [Rename All Files with a Certain Name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24761/rename-all-files-with-a-certain-name) is a nearer dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common `rename` commands that have different syntaxes. You're using a script written for the version that accepts a Perl expression:

```
rename s/expression/replacement/g file...
```

But the one you have installed is the one that accepts both a regex and replacement string, as the error message you saw suggests:

```
rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

(Count yourself lucky, or smart, that you used `\;` instead of `+`.) You can fix this by adjusting your `find` command:

```
find . -type f -name 'botrytis_cinerea_T12345.*' -exec rename botrytis_cinerea_T12345 "$i" {} \;
```

As Kusalananda pointed out in the comments, you're also `cd`ing inside the loop, but never going back to the original directory, so each iteration after the first, you repeatedly attempt to `cd` to a directory that doesn't exist. You might try to fix this by doing another `cd` after `find`, but I'd probably try to avoid that by adjusting the `find` itself:

```bsh
for i in L*; do
    find "$i" -type f -name 'botrytis_cinerea_T12345.*' -exec rename botrytis_cinerea_T12345 "$i" {} \;
done
```

### See also

- [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275254/why-is-the-rename-utility-on-debian-ubuntu-different-than-the-one-on-other-distr)
- [Rename All Files with a Certain Name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24761/rename-all-files-with-a-certain-name)

Comment: Any comment on the `cd` in their code and how the loop is expected to not be able to handle more than one iteration, and what they could do about that?

Comment: @Kusalananda Good point. I'm paranoid about `cd`ing in scripts so I wrote a solution based on changing `find` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes will stop expansion. And {} might need to be escaped Do this instead:

```
find . -type f -name 'botrytis_cinerea_T12345.*' -exec rename "s/botrytis_cinerea_T12345/$i/g" \{\} \;
```

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer, you actually need to escape the "{}"

Comment: Note that their code is stepping down into a directory with `cd`, but that they never change back to the original directory. I would expect the code to eventually generate errors from `cd` too.  Also, `{}` does not need to be escaped as it's not special to the shell (unless the user is using `csh` or `tcsh`).